# Constructor and preStart/postStop hooks NOT invoked for injected Akka RouterActor

Tags: scala, akka, actor, playframework-2.6

I am trying some example in Play Framework (Scala). I'm injecting an actor into controller.

**Configuration**

- **Java** (*1.8.0_144*)
- **Scala** (*2.12.3*)
- **Play** (*2.6.5*)

I have following code:
**ExampleController**

```
class ExampleController @Inject() (
  controllerComponents: ControllerComponents,
  @Named("injected-router") injectedRouterActor: ActorRef,
  @Named("injected") injectedActor: ActorRef)
  extends AbstractController(controllerComponents) {

  def alive = Action {
    injectedActor ! "Hi from Example"
    injectedRouterActor ! "Hi From Example to Router"
    Ok("Alive")
  }

}
```

**InjectedActor**

```
class InjectedActor extends Actor {

  val name = s"IA-${self.path}-${System.nanoTime}"

  println(s"constructor: $name")

  def receive = {
    case m => println(s"$name received: $m")
  }

  override def preStart() = {
    println(s"preStart: $name")
    super.preStart()
  }

}
```

**InjectedRouterActor**

```
class InjectedRouterActor extends Actor {

  val name = s"IRA-${self.path}-${System.nanoTime}"

  println(s"constructor: $name")

  def receive = {
    case m => println(s"$name received: $m")
  }

  override def preStart() = {
    println(s"preStart: $name")
    super.preStart()
  }

}
```

**ChildActor**

```
class ChildActor extends Actor {

  val name = s"CH-${self.path}-${System.nanoTime}"

  println(s"constructor: $name")

  def receive = {
    case m => println(s"$name received: $m")
  }

}
```

**Module**

```
class BindingModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {

  def configure = {
    bindActor[InjectedActor]("injected")
    bindActor[InjectedRouterActor]("injected-router", _ => RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[ChildActor]))
  }

}
```

When I run this, and hit route for *alive*, I see **println**s from all actors visible on console, except for **InjectedRouterActor**.

Unable to understand why? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see `println(s"constructor: $name")` being printed out in `InjectedRouterActor`?

Comment: No, I do not see that `println(...)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Akka routers are special implementation actors that you don't explicitly implement.

In your example `RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[ChildActor])` creates `Props` that would create round robin pool router with routees being actors of type `ChildActor`. You don't really need `InjectedRouterActor`. You might still want to have it if you want to create router based on configuration (see examples in [Akka docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/routing.html#roundrobinpool-and-roundrobingroup)).

If you look at the source of `ActorRefProvider` that creates actors when you use Guice helper

```
class ActorRefProvider[T <: Actor: ClassTag](name: String, props: Props => Props) extends Provider[ActorRef] {

  @Inject private var actorSystem: ActorSystem = _
  @Inject private var injector: Injector = _
  lazy val get = {
    val creation = Props(injector.instanceOf[T])
    actorSystem.actorOf(props(creation), name)
  }
}
```

you can see that it creates default `Props` that gets an instance of `InjectedRouterActor` (the type informations is passed as `T` type parameter) from the injector but, since you provide `props` as a function where the function argument is ignored (`_ => RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[ChildActor])`), it will just ignore `creation` variable. Also `injector.instanceOf[T]` is passed to `Props#apply` as by-name parameter so it is not called right away, so your `InjectedRouterActor` is not created.

Instead of creating binding for the router actor in `configure` you can create it manually:

```
@Provides
@Named("injected-router")
@Singleton
def routerProvider(system: ActorSystem): ActorRef = {
  system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[ChildActor]), name = "injected-router")
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Above code produced same results, as original code, ie. **_No constructor/preStart_**. I guess there is no easy way to do what I needed. I guess I will need to take [this](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html#a-simple-router) route. Thanks.

Comment: I mean you don't need `InjectedRouterActor`. It doesn't have to be created and is not created in your example, hence you don't see any output from it.

Comment: Ok, got it. I misunderstood. As mentioned in my earlier comment, I have started using **_Router_**, instead of **_Router Actor_**. It would be still useful though, to know how to use **Props** passed in `bindActor[InjectedRouterActor]("injected-router", _ => RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[ChildActor]))`.